# while adding the dotenv file i got the error Error : [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
bable.config.js File

plugins: [
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "envName": "APP_ENV",
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "blocklist": null,
      "allowlist": null,
      "blacklist": null, // DEPRECATED
      "whitelist": null, // DEPRECATED
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true,
      "verbose": false
    }]
  ]
```

.env File code

```
API_LOGIN=https://example.in/login
```

login.js

```
import { API_LOGIN } from '@env';

const url = API_LOGIN;
let email = this.state.gmail;
let password = this.state.password;
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  }),
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error : ', error))

  .then((response) => {
    if (response.access_token != undefined) {
      this.setState({
        accessToken: response.access_token,
      });

      if (this.state.accessToken != '') {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('VolunteerHome', {
          AccessToken: this.state.accessToken,
        });
      }
    } else {
      alert('Unauthorised User');
    }
  });
```

In the above code, I have installed `dotenv`. Then I have added the plugin code in the `bable.config.js` file. then I have create `.env` file in root directory and created the environmental variable `API_Login=example.in/login` then import the package in login.js file and use that variable. But I got a network error in my code if I simply add the API URL in the login file then my code run properly. please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use it as a string ?

```
const url = `${API_LOGIN}`;
```

You can also import it like that : `process.env.API_LOGIN`
You also need `require('dotenv').config()`
[More info here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Not working for me I got the same error please help me